# Action method not found in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using 'Pro ASP.NET MVC 5' book by Adam Freeman, working on the Sports Store Web Application that he is using. I tried to redo that example into Computer Store instead and everything was working fine up to the moment when I needed to add extra functionality to the cart ('Summary' partial view).

The 'Summary' PartialView is defined in the Cart Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Summary(Cart cart)
    {
        return PartialView(cart);
    }
```

The Summary View:

```
@model ComputerStore.Domain.Entities.Cart

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Summary";
}

<div class="navbar-right">
    @Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Index", "Cart",
        new { returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery},
        new { @class = "btn btn-default navbar-btn"})
</div>

<div class="navbar-text navbar-right">
    <b>Your cart:</b>
    @Model.Lines.Sum(x => x.Quantity) item(s),
    @Model.CaluclateTotalValue().ToString("c")
</div>
```

And of course, in the _Layout.cshtml file, I call the Action Method:

```
@Html.Action("Summary", "Cart")
```

When I start the Web Application, I get the following error:

```
-A public action method 'Summary' was not found on controller 'ComputerStore.WebUI.Controllers.CartController'.
```

Now, before we mention HttpPost and HttpGet, let me inform you that the Sports Store example works fine using the same code as above. I have tried numerous ways to fix this, and I know that this has been answered multiple times here, but I just don't understand why it doesn't work. Moreover, all packages are updates.

Comment: Just an off topic comment, I notice by your namespaces that you are probably using your domain models as view models. It's well worth the effort early on to start using view models that aren't the same as your domain models.

Comment: @webnoob I am just following the book as it goes. Before this part of the example, Adam uses couple of View Models to pass info. There is actually CartIndexViewModel.cs file that passes Cart info to the View from the CartController. Maybe there will be change to it in the rest of the Chapter.

Comment: Ahh Ok, I've not read the book so apologies. Worth keeping in mind if the book doesn't cover it but good luck!

Comment: Ok, it works now. The parameter passed to the Summary action method is required since it has to return the cart attributes for the current cart session. The cart session is declared in a different class and different namespace. I just deleted the parameter and rewrote again and everything is fine now, which I find odd since yesterday I did the same and it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are you requiring a parameter for your `Summary`.

Try this instead:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Summary()
{
    var cart = new Cart();
    //Do something with cart to load the data.
    return PartialView(cart);
}
```

If you want to pass a param to `Summary` you could do:

```
@Html.Action("Summary", "Cart", new {cart = someExistingCartObject})
```